# Use Google Maps JS API offline

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I worked on google maps js api and made some apps. Now I want to make a desktop application using google maps. How Can I use Use Google Maps JS API offline.

Comment: Have you tried searching documentation on internet ??

Comment: Google Maps requires internet even to show cached tiles (which cache for about 9 months). Openstreetmap tiles with leaflet can show cached tiles while offline, and there are no licensing issues. Mapquest has an API for OSM; Mapbox, and others. Keep in mind, you'll have to fetch any tiles while online to show them offline. If pre-caching a large area, may be wise to only cache 1 zoom level or a handful of zoom levels. Detect if the app is offline, then prevent user from accessing non-cached zoom levels. This is the best alternative I've found to G Maps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API for a desktop app, but Internet connectivity is still required. Offline usage is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use maps offline because google payment relays on this that how many time their api called. So you need internet connectivity for google maps